# Tomcat server is getting failed when only colon is passed in host

Tags: tomcat9

I have upgraded tomcat 8.5.24 to 9.0.29. Tomcat is getting failed because host contains only colon value.

```
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost The host [:] is not valid
 Note: further occurrences of request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:78)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:45)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(AbstractProcessor.java:294)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareRequest(Http11Processor.java:759)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:343)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

That host header is not valid so Tomcat is correctly - as per RFC 7230 - rejecting the request. You need to fix the broken client that is sending in invalid Host header in the request.